# Does this bidiagonal matrix have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Do bidiagonal matrices like the one below have a name?

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_1 & a_2 &  &  & \\
 & a_2 & a_3 &  & \\
 &  & a_3 & a_4 & \\
 &  & & a_4 & a_5\\
 &  & &  & a_5\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: I don't think so. Btw, one should be careful with the word "similar" when it comes to matrices, to avoid confusion. You probably wanted to ask "matrices like the one below".

Comment: Ah, yes, good point